# How to get the name of child in Firebase with Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I can`t get the only `child-name` on the firebase.

```
  mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Diary_Subject")
    if (user != null) {
        mDatabase.child(user.uid).addValueEventListener( object :
            ValueEventListener {
            override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {
                TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File ]| Settings | File Templates.
            }

            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {

                if (snapshot!!.exists()){
                    diarylist.clear()
                val subject = snapshot.toString()
                }
})
```

**This is my firebase**

[image]

I want my program show only the child name like be

```
cgnyft

deveg
```

**but it shows**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use snapshot key:

```
override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
    for (postSnapshot in snapshot.children) {
        val name = postSnapshot.getKey()
        Log.d("Name",name)
    }
}
```

If you want to use "Diary_Subject" you can do it like this:

```
override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
    for (postSnapshot in snapshot.children) {
        val name = postSnapshot.child("Diary_Subject").getValue(String.class)
        Log.d("Name",name)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get value of data snapshot

Try this

```
mDatabase.child(user.uid).addValueEventListener( object :
            ValueEventListener {
            override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {
            }

            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                String name = (String) snapshot.child("Diary_Subject").getValue();
            }
}
```

or you can create a model to store data from dataSnapshot like:

```
data class Subject(
  var Diary_Subject: String
)

mDatabase.child(user.uid).addValueEventListener( object :
            ValueEventListener {
            override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {
            }

            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                val subject = snapshot.getValue(Subject.class);
            }
}
```

Hope this help!